# Firebird: invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)

Tags: python, firebird

I'm following [this](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-set-trans.html) official guide and try to set isolation level in my code like so:

```
import fdb

cnx = fdb.connect(....)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED NO RECORD_VERSION")
```

But running this code in the console results in this error message:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\data\fdb\fdb\fbcore.py", line 3574, in execute
self._ps._execute(parameters)
File "C:\data\fdb\fdb\fbcore.py", line 3291, in _execute
"Error while executing SQL statement:")]
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while executing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -901\n- 
invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)', -901, 335544332)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with that and how can I fix it.

Comment: I've seen `connection.begin()` command in documentation. But from documentation on fdb I could not understand what type of transaction it sets.

Comment: I don't use python with firebird or `SET TRANSACTION` statement, but I think that to execute it you should have already started a transaction. So, in (my) theory, you could start any connection, and then, change the isolation level. But I am not sure as I couldn't test it.

Comment: Forget to mention, that you can read the beta Language Reference instead of the Language Reference Update. See this link http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-transacs-statements.html#fblangref25-transacs-settransac